# How to choose multiple classes not ids in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hover, ellipsis, css

I need to choose multiple classes in Javascript and to make it to work for slide effect on hover.
The elements should be in `<span>` tag.

First element is working:

```
<p id="tweet1">First long text displayed fully on hover</p>
```

Second element, third element and etc is not working:

```
<span class="tweet1">Second long text displayed fully on hover</span>

<span class="tweet1">Third long text displayed fully on hover</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tweet = document.getElementById('tweet1');
tweet.id = 'tweet1';
tweet.className = 'hiding';

var slide_timer,
    max = tweet.scrollWidth,
    slide = function () {
        tweet.scrollLeft += 2;
        if (tweet.scrollLeft < max) {
            slide_timer = setTimeout(slide, 40);
        }
    };

tweet.onmouseover = tweet.onmouseout = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.type === 'mouseover';
    clearTimeout(slide_timer);
    tweet.className = e ? '' : 'hiding';
    if (e) {
        slide();
    } else {
        tweet.scrollLeft = 0;
    }
};
```

CSS:

```
#tweet1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:120px;
}
.hiding {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Full code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it to use gelElementsByClassName().
So the changes to your code would be:

```
<p class="tweet1">First long text displayed fully on hover</p>

var tweet = document.gelElementsByClassName('tweet1');
```

Comment: when i edit tweet.id = 'tweet1'; to tweet.Classname it conflicts with tweet.className = 'hiding'; i don't know what to do

Comment: I didn't tell you to modify tweet.id. The two lines that need to be changed are shown with my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right - it answers my question, but hover effects stops working i need to change something else to make it work and i don't know what to change. Have you seen html result: http://jsfiddle.net/27uuj/3/ ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `document.getElementById('tweet1');` gets an element by its "id" and not by a class. (There's a reason it's named that way.) You probably want `getElementsByClassName()` instead.

Comment: I made it, but hover effect stops working totally. 
When i edit tweet.id = 'tweet1'; to tweet.Classname it conflicts with tweet.className = 'hiding'; i don't know what to do.